# Use a variable for columns in SUMPRODUCT and VLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, variables, vlookup, vba

I'm trying to use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(B$4778,$D$4:$DC$4623,{4,5},0))
```

It works fine but I'd like to try to use a variable for the `{4,5}` portion of the formula (columns in the array to be summed) as the formula needs to change based on sheet inputs before this formula.

I have cells on the sheet that are to be used to set the initial and final columns to be searched (likely 10 columns, but the 10 columns would have to be selected from 90 some columns available).The columns are populations related to each age. So, if I need population of those aged 10 through 15, I'd need to sum up 5 columns. If 20-25, need to sum up 5 different columns.

I tried to use the Columns function but it didn't seem to work for me.

The columns are selected by users entering in cells the upper and lower limits of the search range and then I convert those values to the corresponding numerical column value.

So if they select 5 as lower and 10 as upper limit, I know I have to add 7 to get the correct data column on the data page (column 12) and likewise for upper (column 17).

The entire possible area to search is `$D$4:$DC$4623`. So, in the formula, if I wrote it out long way it would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(B$4778,$D$4:$DC$4623,{12,13,14,15,16,17},0))
```

I'd prefer to write it out using variables, something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(B$4778,$D$4:$DC$4623,{L:U},0))
```

Where variable L would be 12 and variable U would be 17.

Can anyone suggest a way to write the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this array formula:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(B$4778,$D$4:$DC$4623,ROW(INDIRECT(D5 & ":" & E5)),FALSE))
```

Where D5 is the Lower and E5 would be the upper.

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

Or better yet use this non array formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX($D$4:$DC$4623,MATCH(B$4778,$D$4:$D$4623,0),D5):INDEX($D$4:$DC$4623,MATCH(B$4778,$D$4:$D$4623,0),E5))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Both worked a treat as they say in UK! You saved me a bunch of time and frustration. I'm going to use the n0n-array formula. Thank you!